# Why does babel-node-debug not recognize the import command?

Tags: node.js, debugging, babeljs, node-inspector

```
» babel-node-debug --presets es2015 ./updateChains.js
Node Inspector v0.12.10
Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/?port=5858 to start debugging.
Debugging `./scripts/updateChains.js`

Debugger listening on [::]:5858
/mysite/updateChains.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import dotenv from 'dotenv';
```

I think that it uses node inspector v0.12.10 is a part of it, but I'm not sure Any suggestions?

Comment: try npm install --save babel-preset-node6  and than --presets node6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it necessary for you to use `babel-node-debug` which is no longer supported reference link - [babel-node-debug](https://github.com/CrabDude/babel-node-debug). You can use node-inspector [node-inspector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-inspector).

Please! go through this link - [Debugging Node.js with Chrome DevTools](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27). Hope it works, Thanks

Install:

```
npm install -g node-inspector
```

Start:

```
node-debug app.js
```